# How can I add a uniform width outline to WebGL shader drawn circles/ellipses (drawn using edge/distance antialiasing)

Tags: javascript, webgl, shader, fragment-shader

I am drawing circles/ellipses in `WebGL` using a single Quad and a fragment shader, in order to draw them in a resolution independent manner (Edge distance anti-aliasing)

Here is my fragment shader currently:

```
'#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable',
'precision mediump float;',
'varying vec2 coord;',
'vec4 circleColor = vec4(1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0);',
'vec4 outlineColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);',

'uniform float strokeWidth;',          
'float outerEdgeCenter = 0.5 - strokeWidth;',

'void main(void){',

      'float dx = 0.5 - coord.x;',
      'float dy = 0.5 - coord.y;',
      'float distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);',

      'float delta = fwidth(distance);',
      'float alpha = 1.0 - smoothstep(0.45 - delta, 0.45, distance);',
      'float stroke = 1.0 - smoothstep(outerEdgeCenter - delta, outerEdgeCenter + delta, distance);',

      'gl_FragColor = vec4( mix(outlineColor.rgb, circleColor.rgb, stroke), alpha );',                  

'}'
```

This creates an orange circle with a black outline that is perfectly antialiased whatever the size.

[image]

However, as soon as I transform the quad (scale it) in order to turn the circle into an ellipse, the `distance` calculation transforms along with it, causing the outline to also scale.  My understanding is that I would somehow need to account for the quad's transform by inverting it.

[image]

What I would like is for the `distance` to remain uniform even when the quad is transformed, in effect producing a constant width outline around the whole circle/ellipse.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, your fragment shader (FS) is kind of blackbox now (becausethe the code is lack of information).

Your FS is written to work within square space. So it always render circle in space where `x` and `y` are same size ( -1.0; 1.0 interval).

While quad is transformed outside (in VS or anywhere else) and there is no way how to reflect that transformation in FS yet.

To solve the problem, I suggest to push an additional information into FS about the scaling. Something like [Shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/) provides in shader inputs:

```
uniform vec3 iResolution; // viewport resolution (in pixels)
```

except this wont be the resolution of the screen size, but the information about quad transformation, so something like:

```
varying vec2 trans;
// where value (1.0, 1.0) mean no transformation
```

Then you can use this value to calculate different stroke. Instead of inverting the transformation for the current stroke, I would rather calculate unique dx and dy values for it.

There are more ways to achieve the working solution and it depends on how do you want to use it later (what kinds of transformations should be possible etc.). So I present only the basic but the easiest solution.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand what you're saying.  So presuming I have passed in the width and height of the ellipse as uniforms.  How would I go about calculating the stroke?

Comment: Well if you push widht and height instead and you dont transform it from outside, then it's kind of different game now. You really must decide what do you want: draw ellipses and custom shapes in fragment shader? Or do transformations from outside? The question is beginning to be to large.

Comment: In case you want to work with fragment shader, I strongly recomend shadertoy. It is quite smaller then webgl and easier to understand. This demo I have written right could be some hint for you: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4scSWr

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  If I pushed in the width/height surely I could then work out the scale by calculating the texelSizes - (1.0 / width) and (1.0 / height).  I'm just unsure how I could then apply that to the  stroke.

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look at your shadertoy demo. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot... From your Answer and your comments I was able to work it out and I now understand fully where I was going wrong.

Comment: anytime ;) And if you accidentaly start digging deeper then you should, read this stuff: http://iquilezles.org/www/index.htm
It is kind of fragment shader gate