# Implement antialiasing logic for line segments and triangles in GLSL shaders

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, shader, antialiasing

I'm building 2D Graph structure based on Three.js, all elements of the graph (nodes, edges, triangles for arrows) calculated in shaders. I was able to reach a good level of antialiasing for nodes (circles) but stuck with same task for lines and triangles.

I was able to reach a good antialiasing results for nodes (circles) with and without stroke following this question: [How can I add a uniform width outline to WebGL shader drawn circles/ellipses (drawn using edge/distance antialiasing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142039/how-can-i-add-a-uniform-width-outline-to-webgl-shader-drawn-circles-ellipses-dr) , my code, responsible for antialiasing alpha:

```
`float strokeWidth = 0.09;
 float outerEdgeCenter = 0.5 - strokeWidth;
 float d = distance(vUV, vec2(.5, .5));
 float delta = fwidth(d);
 float alpha = 1.0 - smoothstep(0.45 - delta, 0.45, d);
 float stroke = 1.0 - smoothstep(outerEdgeCenter - delta, 
 outerEdgeCenter + delta, d);`
```

But now I'm completely stack with edges and triangles to do same stuff.

Here is an example of shapes images that I have now (on non retina displays):

[image: arrow]

[image: line]

To reduce under-sampling artifacts I want to do similar algorithms (as for circles) directly in shaders by manipulating alpha and already find some materials related to this topic:

1. https://thebookofshaders.com/glossary/?search=smoothstep - seems to be the closest solution but unfortunately I wasn't able to implement it properly and figure out how to set up y equation for segmented lines.
2. https://discourse.threejs.org/t/shader-to-create-an-offset-inward-growing-stroke/6060/12 - last answer, looks promising but not give me proper result.
3. https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4dcfW8 - also do not give proper result.

Here is an examples of my shaders for lines and triangles:

**Line VertexShader (is a slightly adapted version of WestLangley's LineMaterial shader):**

```
`precision highp float;

#include <common>
#include <color_pars_vertex>
#include <fog_pars_vertex>
#include <logdepthbuf_pars_vertex>
#include <clipping_planes_pars_vertex>

uniform float linewidth;
uniform vec2 resolution;
attribute vec3 instanceStart;
attribute vec3 instanceEnd;
attribute vec3 instanceColorStart;
attribute vec3 instanceColorEnd;
attribute float alphaStart;
attribute float alphaEnd;
attribute float widthStart;
attribute float widthEnd;
varying vec2 vUv;
varying float alphaTest;

void trimSegment( const in vec4 start, inout vec4 end ) {

    // trim end segment so it terminates between the camera plane and the near plane
    // conservative estimate of the near plane
    float a = projectionMatrix[ 2 ][ 2 ]; // 3nd entry in 3th column
    float b = projectionMatrix[ 3 ][ 2 ]; // 3nd entry in 4th column
    float nearEstimate = - 0.5 * b / a;
    float alpha = ( nearEstimate - start.z ) / ( end.z - start.z );

    end.xyz = mix( start.xyz, end.xyz, alpha );
}

void main() {                
    #ifdef USE_COLOR
        vColor.xyz = ( position.y < 0.5 ) ? instanceColorStart : instanceColorEnd;
        alphaTest = ( position.y < 0.5 ) ? alphaStart : alphaEnd;
    #endif

        float aspect = resolution.x / resolution.y;
        vUv = uv;

        // camera space
        vec4 start = modelViewMatrix * vec4( instanceStart, 1.0 );
        vec4 end = modelViewMatrix * vec4( instanceEnd, 1.0 );

        // special case for perspective projection, and segments that terminate either in, or behind, the camera plane
        // clearly the gpu firmware has a way of addressing this issue when projecting into ndc space
        // but we need to perform ndc-space calculations in the shader, so we must address this issue directly
        // perhaps there is a more elegant solution -- WestLangley

        bool perspective = ( projectionMatrix[ 2 ][ 3 ] == - 1.0 ); // 4th entry in the 3rd column

        if (perspective) {
            if (start.z < 0.0 && end.z >= 0.0) {
                trimSegment( start, end );
            } else if (end.z < 0.0 && start.z >= 0.0) {
                trimSegment( end, start );
            }
        }

        // clip space
        vec4 clipStart = projectionMatrix * start;
        vec4 clipEnd = projectionMatrix * end;

        // ndc space
        vec2 ndcStart = clipStart.xy / clipStart.w;
        vec2 ndcEnd = clipEnd.xy / clipEnd.w;

        // direction
        vec2 dir = ndcEnd - ndcStart;

        // account for clip-space aspect ratio
        dir.x *= aspect;
        dir = normalize( dir );

        // perpendicular to dir
        vec2 offset = vec2( dir.y, - dir.x );

        // undo aspect ratio adjustment
        dir.x /= aspect;
        offset.x /= aspect;

        // sign flip
        if ( position.x < 0.0 ) offset *= - 1.0;

        // endcaps, to round line corners
        if ( position.y < 0.0 ) {
           // offset += - dir;
        } else if ( position.y > 1.0 ) {
           // offset += dir;
        }

        // adjust for linewidth
        offset *= (linewidth * widthStart);

        // adjust for clip-space to screen-space conversion // maybe resolution should be based on viewport ...
        offset /= resolution.y;

        // select end
        vec4 clip = ( position.y < 0.5 ) ? clipStart : clipEnd;

        // back to clip space
        offset *= clip.w;

        clip.xy += offset;

        gl_Position = clip;

        vec4 mvPosition = ( position.y < 0.5 ) ? start : end; // this is an approximation

        #include <logdepthbuf_vertex>
        #include <clipping_planes_vertex>
        #include <fog_vertex>
   }`
```

**Line FragmentShader:**

```
`precision highp float;

   #include <common>
       #include <color_pars_fragment>
       #include <fog_pars_fragment>
       #include <logdepthbuf_pars_fragment>
       #include <clipping_planes_pars_fragment>

   uniform vec3 diffuse;
       uniform float opacity;
       varying vec2 vUv;
       varying float alphaTest;

   void main() {                   
     if ( abs( vUv.y ) > 1.0 ) {
                 float a = vUv.x;
                 float b = ( vUv.y > 0.0 ) ? vUv.y - 1.0 : vUv.y + 1.0;
                 float len2 = a * a + b * b;

                 if ( len2 > 1.0 ) discard;
           }

           vec4 diffuseColor = vec4( diffuse, alphaTest );

           #include <logdepthbuf_fragment>
           #include <color_fragment>

           gl_FragColor = vec4( diffuseColor.rgb, diffuseColor.a );

           #include <premultiplied_alpha_fragment>
           #include <tonemapping_fragment>
           #include <encodings_fragment>
           #include <fog_fragment>

   }`
```

**Triangle vertex shader:**

```
`precision highp float;

       uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
       uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
       uniform float zoomLevel;
       attribute vec3 position;
       attribute vec3 vertexPos;
       attribute vec3 color;
       attribute float alpha;
       attribute float xAngle;
       attribute float yAngle;
       attribute float xScale;
       attribute float yScale;
       varying vec4 vColor;

       // transforms the 'positions' geometry with instance attributes
       vec3 transform( inout vec3 position, vec3 T) {

            position.x *= xScale;
            position.y *= yScale;

            // Rotate the position
            vec3 rotatedPosition = vec3(
               position.x * yAngle + position.y * xAngle,
               position.y * yAngle - position.x * xAngle, 0);

            position = rotatedPosition + T;

            // return the transformed position
            return position;
       }

       void main() {                
            vec3 pos = position;
            vColor = vec4(color, alpha);

            // transform it
            transform(pos, vertexPos);

            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( pos, 1.0 );
       }`
```

**Triangle FragmentShader:**

```
`precision highp float;
       varying vec4 vColor;

       void main() {                    
         gl_FragColor = vColor;
       }`
```

Will really appreciate any help on how to do it or suggestion of right direction for further investigations. Thank you!

Comment: If it was me I'd texture that stuff. Make a texture transparent on the edges, let the sampler linearly interpolate what I get. Lines in particular are not going to work. GL only draws single pixel lines, to draw antialiased lines requires using triangles since there are places where you need 2 or 3 pixels drawn where GL will only draw 1. But since you'd be using triangles a texture would work just fine. It also has the advantage of not generally not needing special shaders.

Comment: Another suggestion, look through the [skia code](https://skia.org). Skia is the library that renders most of the text, css, svg and Canvas2D in Chrome, Firefox, and Android. It clearly anti-aliases. In fact they have a webassembly version which means you can install the [shader editor extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shader-editor/ggeaidddejpbakgafapihjbgdlbbbpob?hl=en) then run their [webassembly demo](https://skia.org/user/modules/canvaskit), then [inspect the shaders](https://imgur.com/D7pHvLq) and probably get an idea of what they're doing.

Comment: https://blog.mapbox.com/drawing-antialiased-lines-with-opengl-8766f34192dc